# Adding details to JSON object : Javascript functions and promises

Tags: javascript, function, promise

I have the following structure:

Company has list of employees having only emp ids. 
Another Util function will provide emp details taking in list of emp ids.
I need to write a function which would attach the details to the matched emp ids, if details exist.

My jsbin project : http://jsbin.com/bacasuzixa/edit?html,js,output

```
        //jshint esnext:true
    function write(message) {
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += message + '<br/>';
    }
    function newParagraph() { 
      write("");
    }

    var PartialResponse=
    {

        "data": [
            {
                "company": "aaaa",
                "employees": [
                    {
                        "empid": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "empid": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "empid": "3"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "company": "bbbb",
                "employees": []
            }
        ]
    }

    let queryEmps = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function(){
        resolve(
          {

            "EmpProfile": {
              "Details": [
                {

                  "empid": "1",

                  "details": {
                    "email": "aaaa@bb.com",
                    "firstName": "aaaa"
                  }
                },
                 {
                  "empid": "2",
                  "details": {
                    "email": "ccc@ddd.com",
                    "firstName": "ccc"
                  }
                } 
              ]
            }
          }

        ); // Yay! Everything went well!
      }, 1);
    });


    newParagraph();

    newParagraph();

    function adEmployeeDetails( PartialResponse)
        {
                for (let i = 0, len = PartialResponse.data.length; i < len; i++) {
                if(PartialResponse.data[i].employees.length>0){
                    let empids = PartialResponse.data[i].employees.map(a => a.empid);
                    //returns array of Details
                    queryEmps
                    .then(response =>addDetails(response,PartialResponse.data[i].employees))
                    .then(response => write("LOCATION1 : PartialResponse: " + JSON.stringify(PartialResponse)))
                    /*
                    LOCATION1: Wanted result: 
                    {
                    "data": [
                        {
                        "company": "aaaa",
                        "employees": [
                            {
                            "empid": "1",
                            "profile": {
                                "email": "aaaa@bb.com",
                                "firstName": "aaaa"
                            }
                            },
                            {
                            "empid": "2",
                            "profile": {
                                "email": "ccc@ddd.com",
                                "firstName": "ccc"
                            }
                            },
                            {
                            "empid": "3"
                            }
                        ]
                        },
                        {
                        "company": "bbbb",
                        "employees": []
                        }
                    ]
                    }
                    */


                }
                //LOCATION2
    //             write("LOCATION2 : PartialResponse: " + JSON.stringify(PartialResponse));
            }   
            //LOCATION3
    //       write(LOCATION3 : PartialResponse: " + JSON.stringify(PartialResponse));
            return PartialResponse;
        }   

    function addDetails(userinfo,varEmployees){
      for (var i = 0, len = varEmployees.length; i < len; i++) {
        userinfo.EmpProfile.Details.forEach(
          function(childItem) {
            if ((childItem.empid == varEmployees[i].empid)) {
              varEmployees[i].profile = childItem.details;
            }
          });
      }
        return varEmployees;
    }

    newParagraph();
    //LOCATION4
    write("adEmployeeDetails: " +  
    JSON.stringify(adEmployeeDetails(PartialResponse)));
```

I want the results that appear at LOCATION1 to get carried over to LOCATION2,  LOCATION3 and ultimately to LOCATION4. I am not sure what I missing..

My jsbin project: http://jsbin.com/bacasuzixa/edit?html,js,output

I am not an expert in Javascript. Thank you for your help...

Comment: Let me rerphase my question :

So we are in a loop in a function. Inside the loop we call a function which returns a promise for each time it iterates.

You need to carry the results of this iteration to the outside scope and finally return from a function. How can I do that..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to get final result from promise and use the result to do something, right?

Let's assume that what you want to achieve is:

1. Get list of employees (PartialResponse in your code)
2. Get list of employees' profiles (queryEmps in your code)

and both of these two data are return as `Promise`.

3. Combine the employees and its profile.
4. Display the result (or anything you want to do).

A possible way is using `Promise.all`

```
// Suppose that we have two functions which return 'Promise'
fetchEmployee()
fetchEmployeeDetail()
```

**Get data with Promise.all**

```
Promise.all([
  fetchEmployee(),
  fetchEmployeeDetail(),
])
```

**Combine the data**

```
Primise.all([
  fetchEmployee(),
  fetchEmployeeDetail(),
])
.then(result => {
  // The result is an array, and the order of the element in 
  // this array is the order of the Promise that 
  // you passed to Promise.all
  let listOfEmployee = result[0];
  let listOfDetail = result[1];

  // Do your combination logic here.

  return result; // Return the result that you combined here.
})
```

**Use what you have done**

```
Primise.all([
  fetchEmployee(),
  fetchEmployeeDetail(),
])
.then(results => {
  // The result is an array, and the order of the element in 
  // this array is the order of the Promise that 
  // you passed to Promise.all
  let listOfEmployee = results[0];
  let listOfDetail = results[1];

  // Do your combination logic here.

  return result; // Return the result that you combined here.
})
.then(result => {
  // the result here is what you have combined in the previous step.
  // You can do anything you want here
})
```

Here is a example for you:
[JSBin example](https://jsbin.com/husivot/edit?js,console,output)